# HTML entities not recognized and not displayed when retrieved from ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, encoding, browser

This happens in all tested browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Opera ...)

Some HTML entities are are swallowed and not displayed when retrieved from ajax. The same HTML entity is displayed when it is hardcoded in the HTML source file.

***Here is the actual output:*** (the entity is not display nether in the web page nor in the console)

[image: the entity is not display nether in the web page nor in the console]

***Here is the expected output:***

[image]

Here is the javascript that retrieves the entity:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function injectEntity(){
       var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", "entity.php", true);
      
       xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
           if(xhr.readyState == 4){
               var doc = xhr.responseXML;
             console.log(xhr.responseText);
             var div = document.getElementById("container");   
               div.appendChild(doc.getElementById("the-entity"));
           }   
       }
      xhr.send(null);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <a href="#" onclick="injectEntity();">inject the following entity:</a> &#146;
  <div id="container">
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the php file that is used to retrieve the entity:

```
<?php

header('Content-type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8');

$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$tag = $xml->createElement('b','&#146;');
$tag->setAttribute("id","the-entity");
$xml->appendChild($tag);
echo $xml->saveXML();

?>
```

Comment: My guess would be that you have to parse the text if you want the entities to be replaced. You can parse the text with `innerHTML`. So, instead of `appendNode`, use `innerHTML` to add the content to the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You want `&#8217;`, not `&#146;` (which is an unprintable control character)

Comment: Thanks. This is true but why the HTML entity &#146; is correctly displayed when it is put in the HTML source page.